# Self-Employed Visa and Living in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas

I'm from Kosovo, currently self-employed (have a business and profit about 1000£/month). Last year I got a UK visitor visa, visited UK and liked the living there. I'm looking for options to move and live in UK.

I've some personal websites and I develop and manage some clients' websites that have contracts for next 1-2 years.

Is there any visa type like a Business visa that allows me to move to UK, register my business there, create bank account for my business and live there as self-employed, or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the UK's page on work visas](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas).  I think you want one of these visas under *Investor, business development and talent visas,* but they do require endorsement:

- [Innovator visa](https://www.gov.uk/innovator-visa) (requires £50,000 investment and endorsement by "an approved body.")
- [Start-up visa](https://www.gov.uk/start-up-visa) (requires endorsement from "an authorised body that is either a UK higher education institution [or] a business organisation with a history of supporting UK entrepreneurs.")